# Fullcalendar.js can't add events

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar

I have a Laravel project and I want to add events before fullcalendar.js renders the calendar. But can't do it by giving event objects array and ajax URL. Here is what I try tried:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            height: '100%',
            expandRows: true,
            slotMinTime: '08:00',
            slotMaxTime: '20:00',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            initialDate: '2020-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            events: '/getConcerts',
            locale: 'tr',
            selectable: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

Even pre-configured events doesn't render:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            height: '100%',
            expandRows: true,
            slotMinTime: '08:00',
            slotMaxTime: '20:00',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            initialDate: '2020-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Deneme',
                    start: '2021-09-13',
                    allDay: true
                }
            ],
            locale: 'tr',
            selectable: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
        });
        calendar.render();
```

Here is the `/getConcerts` route function:

```
$concerts = Concert::query()->whereStatus('1')->get();
$collection = collect();

foreach($concerts as $concert){
    $start_date = new DateTime($concert->start_date);
    $collection->push([
        'title' => json_decode($concert->title, true)['tr'],
        'start' => $start_date->format('Y-m-d'),
        'startTime' => $start_date->format('H:i')
    ]);
}

return response()->json(['concerts' => $collection]);
```

Also tried this in my view:

```
    const eventsObj = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: '/getConcerts',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
                for (const concert of response.concerts) {
                    eventsObj.push({
                    title: concert.title,
                    start: concert.start,
                    startTime: concert.startTime
                });
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(eventsObj);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            height: '100%',
            expandRows: true,
            slotMinTime: '08:00',
            slotMaxTime: '20:00',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            initialDate: '2020-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            events: eventsObj,
            locale: 'tr',
            selectable: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
```

I don't understand why I can't add events to the calendar in these 2 ways.

Comment: what are you seeing in the console log fo the events object? Is the format/syntax for events correct? eg. [{ title: 'All Day Event',start: '2019-11-11'}] ?

Comment: @James as far as doc goes format and syntax is correct. I don't see anything when I run `calendar.getEvents()` function but empty array.

Comment: In that case I would hold off on loading the calendar until your events have returned from the Ajax request. Otherwise it will load the calendar before you've got your events.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either way.

Comment: Strange. Can you add the console.log line below the document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()  line - this will tell you if the events are empty when you process the calendar. If it is empty, then it's either coming back from Ajax as empty, or the calendar is still being created before the Ajax response is coming back.

Comment: I can confirm that ajax returns something. See the edited question, it even gets stranger.

Comment: isn't it defaultDate not initalDate?

Comment: which version of the FullCalendar.js files are you using? Could you maybe update to the version used on my demo here: https://codepen.io/jtibbles/pen/bGRRKyv  because it could be you are using some older variable names

Comment: Latest version.

Comment: Your pre-configured demo above has an event in 2021, but the init start date is in 2020. Was that correct? - either way I've updated my codepen example with your data and I can see the event when manually added (you have to swipe through to Sept 2021 to see it as the init date starts in 2020 as per your demo) - https://codepen.io/jtibbles/pen/bGRRKyv. Please try using that sample code with your ajax request instead.